# How to print list from input with specific items

Tags: python, list, input, append

How to print list with from input with specific items? For example with names which ends with x.
I've got this code

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name == "":
        break
    list = []
    namex = name.endswith("x")
    if name == namex:
        list.append(name)
    print (list)
```

but when i try to print list it gives me nothing:

```
>>> Enter your name: alex
    Enter your name: james
    Enter your name: abcx
    Enter your name: 
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that namex is a [boolean](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool), not a [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

```
>>> 'abc'.endswith("x")
False
>>> 'abcx'.endswith("x")
True
```

This means that any equality comparison between a string and a boolean will return false. You want to trigger the "if" statement if the statement ends with "x", or:

```
names = []
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name == "":
        break
    namex = name.endswith("x")
    # namex is a boolean type, which if it is True, will trigger an if statement
    if namex:
        names.append(name)
print(names)
```

Comment: i think printing the list should be outside the loop

Comment: Fair, editing.

Then the names definition should occur outside anyway, and I forgot about overriding the builtin list.

Answer (score 2):

```
namex = name.endswith("x")
if name == namex:
```

Does not do what you think it does. `name.endswith("x")` returns `True` or `False`. Should be

```
if name.endswith("x"):
```

instead.

```
names = []
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name == "":
        break
    if name.endswith("x"):
        names.append(name)
print (names)
```

List comprehension [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) version:

```
>>> [name for name in iter(input, '') if name.endswith('x')]
dsf
sdfdsf
dsffdx
sx

['dsffdx', 'sx']
```

Comment: Dude! you were faster by 43 seconds! ;)

Comment: Upvoted just for the use of list comprehension and iter() function it would be nice if you could add the link to iter() method

Answer (score 1):

Here, I am storing all the names ending with 'x' in `namex_list` instead of using the `list`(also a built-in variable) variable you used before.

Also, i am assigning `namex_list` as an empty list before the while condition and printing the `namex_list` at the end outside of `while`.

```
namex_list = []
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name == "":
        break     
    if name.endswith("x"):
        namex_list.append(name)
print (namex_list)
```

Also, `name == namex` does not check what you are trying to achieve because of the comparison between string values and boolean values.

For example:

```
>>> name1 = 'abc'
>>> name2 = 'abcx'
>>> namex1 = name1.endswith('x')
>>> namex2 = name2.endswith('x')

>>> namex1
False
>>> namex2
True

>>> name1 == namex1    
False
>>> name2 == namex2
False
```

You should use an `if` instead to achieve what you are trying to achieve in your code above:

```
if name.endswith("x"):
```